# jdb-Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java, jdb

i would like to use jdb,i'm trying to run it couple of hours already and i have searched all over the examples there are.i think its a syntax problem..
i'm trying to run it like this:

```
>jdb Main
Initializing jdb ...
>run
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
VM Started:Error: Could not find or load main class Main
The application exited
```

//-----------------------------
I also tried to put the full path which is:

> C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Try/src/pkgtry/Main.java

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -sourcepath and -classpath. sourcepath should point to source codes (*.java) and classpath should point to compiled code (*.class).

It's also good idea to put your source inside package (in case of Java just create directory and put sources there).

Answer (score 0):

Use full name of source file with extension (filename.java)
in directory with your source file:

```
C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Try/src/pkgtry>
>jdb Main.java
Initializing jdb ...
>run
```

or

```
C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Try/src/pkgtry>    
>jdb
Initializing jdb ...
>run Main.java
```